# How to specify number of workers in sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

sagemaker API let's you create model ( see sample below) , are there any paramters that we can pass , as environment variables that can specify number of workers/cpu for certain instance type that we choose?

```
def model():
  sagemaker.create_model(
       ModelName = 'mymodel'
       PrimaryContainer = {
           'ModelDataUrl': "s3://modelloation",
           'Environment': {

            }
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

i don't know if it can help but for inference you need to pass the env var like this : `'SAGEMAKER_MODEL_SERVER_WORKERS':'4'` so it can spawn multiple workers

Comment: Whats the default value for ```SAGEMAKER_MODEL_SERVER_WORKERS``` ?

Comment: I believe it depends on the docker and instance you are using.

Comment: It looks like this was still an issue when using PyTorch models until March 2023 ([PR](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-pytorch-inference-toolkit/pull/136), [issue](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-pytorch-inference-toolkit/issues/99)), and I'm not sure if the fix is in production yet.

Answer (score 1):

Once you create the model, you have two options to host your model for inference.

If you need real-time inference, you can use the [CreateEndpointConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateEndpointConfig.html) API to specify the instance types and count, and then create an endpoint using the specified configuration.

If you need batch inference, you can use the TransformResources section to specify the resources ([CreateTransformJob](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTransformJob.html) API).